# tomcat and spring session persistence

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

Iam running spring4.1 mvc project in tomcat7. And Iam trying to do session persistence in Database. The session data is properly serialized and stored in database, but while restoring the session I am getting an error classNotFound. I think that is spring's proxy class.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gksoft.beans.SessionData$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$97cb3e15

please help me to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the jar / dependency holding the package com.gksoft.beans. This is neither part of any Spring Framework or Tomcat.

Comment: Actually that class is dynamically generated class by spring, we won't have physical source file